# Printing using already assigned variables

Tags: python

I am learning Python and am having some trouble printing already assigned variables.  For example:

Write Python statements that print the next formatted outputs using the already assigned variable *first, middle,* and *last:*

```
>>>first = 'Marlena'
>>>last = 'Sigel'
>>>middle = 'Mae'
```

```
a) Sigel, Marlena Mae
b) Sigel, Marlena M.
c) Marlena M. Sigel
d) M. M. Sigel
```

--- for part a) I am getting this:

```
>>> print (last, first, sep=' , ' +  middle)
Sigel , MaeMarlena
```

how do I get a space between Mae and Marlena?

For b, c, and d, how do I do this without changing these to strings?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to use python's [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). This is the format that Guido prefers for python3.

a) Sigel, Marlena Mae

```
print(u"{0}, {1} {2}".format(last, first, middle))
```

b) Sigel, Marlena M.

```
print(u"{0}, {1} {2}.".format(last, first, middle[0]))
```

c) Marlena M. Sigel

```
print(u"{0} {1}. {2}".format(first, middle[0], last))
```

d) M. M. Sigel

```
print(u"{0}. {1}. {2}".format(first[0], middle[0], last))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has string as the default type when it comes to arguments in print function. Use this:

```
# Sigel, Marlena Mae
print(", ".join([last,first+" "+middle]))

# Sigel, Marlena M.
print(", ".join([last,first+" "+middle[0]+"."]))
```

The rest should be understandable for you!

If you don't want to get into "join" function and want to get it done as a new Python learner, the simpler version:

```
# Sigel, Marlena Mae
print(last+", "+first+" "+middle)

# Sigel, Marlena M.
print(last+", "+first+" "+middle[0]+".")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first='Marlena'
middle='Mae'
last='Sigel'

print('%s, %s %s' % (last, middle, first))
print('%s, %s %s.' % (last, first, middle[0]))
print('%s %s. %s' % (first, middle[0], last))
print('%s. %s. %s' % (first[0], middle[0], last))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way of .format

```
print "{}, {}  {}".format(last,first,middle)
print "{}, {}  {}.".format(last,first,middle[0])
print "{} {}.  {}".format(first,middle[0],last)
print "{}. {}.  {}".format(first[0],middle[0],last)
```